# Delete all version of S3 object using lifecycle rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket with multiple folders with versioning enabled.
Out of these multiple folders I want to complete delete one folder as it has multiple delete marker.
I am using Lifecycle rule to delete the objects but not sure if it will work for specific folder.
In Lifecycle Rule, If I specify the folder_name/ as a prefix and expiration rule as 1 day after creation for all and  current versions.
Will it delete all the objects and its versions ?
Can someone please confirm ?
The other folders are quite critical so can't mess with the rule to test.

Comment: It should work, but it might take longer than a day to happen. The Lifecycle rules run at some mysterious time, so give it a couple of days to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that you can delete at folder level instead of entire bucket.  We have a rule that does the exact same thing (although 7 days instead of 1).  I will echo John's point that after initial setup, it will take time to do the deletion.  You should see progress STARTING within 1 hour, but actual completion may take a while.